# SP Online : flow for external user

Tags: sharepoint-online, user, external-users, flow, ms-flow

- Is there a way how to share flows to exeternal users?
- Or way how to give licences to external users?

  I need them to log in with microsoft account not with a organization account.

  Thanks for ideas.

Comment: 1) How is the Flow going to be triggered? Manually? Based on a list item? Via PowerApps? 2) What does this flow supposed to do exactly?

Comment: Its going to be triggered manually. But im not able to share this flow to external users

Comment: There is no way to share a flow with an external user. But maybe there could be a workaround. For example, you can trigger your MS Flow when a SharePoint list item is created. Just choose a trigger that is not a manual button. Then grant permissions to that SharePoint list to the external user. You can do this trick with many other connectors. For Example, you can use MS Form as a trigger.

Comment: I use this flow for selected file si I guess theres no other way how to workaround that.

Comment: There is no workaround for the case you describe. Unless you create a new user in your local Office 365 tenant and assign a SPO + Flow license for that account.

Answer (score 0):

You can add SharePoint Lists or Libraries as 'run-only users' to your Flow.  This means that anyone, internal or external, who already has access to your list or library will now also be able to trigger related Flows.

Please view the following Microsoft Reference for step-by-step instructions: [Flows “owned by” SharePoint lists and libraries](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/business-applications-release-notes/april18/microsoft-flow/sharepoint-lists-libraries)